# Converting string into Date and Time Values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please, How do I converts strings like this:
 `2021-01-15 14:22:56.692234+00:00` into datetime value as this :

```
Jan. 15, 2021, 3:07 p.m.
```

Comment: Also, 14h is 2PM, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime` module to do the parsing.

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime('2019-01-04T16:41:24+0200', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `datetime` module, specifically, `strptime` to convert a string into a `datetime` object, then `strftime` to print it out in your desired format.

```py
from datetime import datetime
parsed = datetime.strptime(
    '2021-01-15 14:22:56.692234+00:00',
    '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'
)
formatted = parsed.strftime('%b. %d, %Y, %-I:%M %p')
print(formatted)
```

This will give:

```
'Jan. 15, 2021, 2:22 PM'
```

There are no way to reproduce exactly `p.m.` but to replace it manually:

```py
formatted = formatted.replace('AM', 'a.m.').replace('PM', 'p.m.')
print(formatted)
```

Which gives:

```
'Jan. 15, 2021, 2:22 p.m.'
```

Comment: I got this error `ValueError: time data '2021-01-15 14:22:56.692234+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'` while trying to use your example.

Comment: @MichaelAjanaku weird. I tried both on Mac and Linux, so it shouldn't be an OS thing. Are you on Windows? (though I doubt it makes a difference)

Comment: Na, I am on Mac

Comment: I have seen why, there is a `.` instead of a `,` on the 6th line.

Comment: @MichaelAjanaku Ah that's why, you should have just copied it verbatim.